# Как отправлять значение компонента формы checked в обработчик

Tags: html, php, form

Если `checkbox` выделен галочкой, то в обработчик летит 1, иначе 0

Answer (score 2):

```
// PHP
$ch = isset($_POST['ch']) ? $_POST['ch'] : 0;
// HTML
<input type="checkbox" name="ch" value="1">
```

Answer (score 1):

Даете чекбоксу атрибут `name` и в обработчике пользуетесь этим чекбоксом по атрибуту `name`
значение `checked` передаст в обработчик 1!